# How to rewrite this kind of url?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

how can I rewrite this kind of url in nginx

`http://example.org/index.php?p=discussion/7/topic`

into this

```
http://example.org/discussion/7/topic
```

I used location

```
/forum {try_files $uri $uri/ @forum;}


location @forum {rewrite ^/forum(.+)$ /forum/index.php?p=$1 last;}
```

Thank you for advices :)

Comment: Just use `rewrite`. What's the problem?

Comment: well I used location /forum {try_files $uri $uri/ @forum;}


location @forum {rewrite ^/forum(.+)$ /forum/index.php?p=$1 last;} but it won't work..

Comment: can you please update your question as it is a bit hard reading configuration in the comments.

Comment: it seems to me your configuration is the opposite of what you want you ask it to rewrite forumsomething into /forum/index.php?p=something.

Comment: also this is possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/160790/nginx-rewrite-for-an-url-with-parameters

Comment: well its not working for me .. I used this location = / {
rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?p=$1 last;
}

Comment: I removed my answer, you should write your own so it will be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Rewrite url from Srgrn was right, I was just dumb and didn't check my routes to CSS. Thank you.